# Making a Handlebars Template from a Firebase JSON

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that worked fine using the old fashioned XMLHttpRequest to get the JSON array from https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/pets-data.json. Below is the working code for that. But my JSON from Firebase looks different, like this: http://pastebin.com/JaYVVzwN. Every entry of mine also has a key, while the LearnWebCode JSON is just an array. Mine is also missing the parent key ('Projects'), which further complicates the transition. I'm thinking it might be due to the line with `const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Projects');` (see the very bottom where I post my attempted javascript)

**handlebars-project.js:** Old-fashioned XMLHttpRequest

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/pets-data.json');
ourRequest.onload = function() {
    if (ourRequest.status >= 200 && ourRequest.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        createHTML(data);
    } else {
        console.log("We connected to the server, but it returns an error.");
    }
};

ourRequest.onerror = function () {
    console.log("Connection error");
};

ourRequest.send();

function createHTML (petsData) {
    var rawTemplate = document.getElementById("petsTemplate").innerHTML;
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
    var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(petsData);

    var petsContainer = document.getElementById("pets-container");
    petsContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;
}
```

And here's the working HTML/Handlebars code:

**card-handlebars.php:** Basic template I want to use (it makes a little card. I want a lot of these, one for every item under the Projects key from the Firebase JSON)

```
<div class="ui stackable cards" id="pets-container"></div>

<script id="petsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each pets}}
<div class="ui red card" id="ui_card">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="right floated header">
            {{species}}
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <p>{{name}}</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">      
        <div class="description">
            <a href="project_details.php">
            Description goes here. Some lorem ipsum should be fine here for now. Lorem ipsum dolor mit aset. Lorem ipsum dolor mit aset. Lorem ipsum dolor mit aset. Lorem ipsum dolor mit aset. 
            </a>     
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="extra content">
        <span class="right floated" id="card_weeks_ago">
            2 weeks ago
        </span>
        <img class="ui avatar image" src="/examples/assets/images/avatar/elliot.png"> Elliot Fu
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Now I want to switch that first `handlebars-project.js` code over to using firebase instead.

To be clear, I want my page to be populated with a bunch of these cards (I'm using Semantic UI) for every item under the Projects key (Project-1, Project-2, Project-3, etc.) from a single Firebase fetch. It's already being stringified to JSON. I want the looping to stay in handlebars (HTML), not in the javascript. And this isn't using Node.js.

Here's a look at my actual Firebase table:

[image: Firebase List]

Here's my attempt at the javascript:

**handlebars-firebase-project.js:** Not working. This is where the crux of the whole issue is. It should be a simple fix but I'm no JS expert.

```
(function() {

  // <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase.js"></script>

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAC1MEF59loMVRA7zyaMhn6uHrp4i2OPNw",
    authDomain: "website-171c8.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://website-171c8.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "website-171c8.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "642759134369"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Create references
  const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Projects');

  //Sync object changes (HTML)
  dbRefObject.on('value', snap => {

    var rawTemplate = document.getElementById("petsTemplate").innerHTML;
    var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
    var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(JSON.stringify(snap.val(), null, 3));

    var petsContainer = document.getElementById("pets-container");
    petsContainer.innerHTML = ourGeneratedHTML;

  });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your firebase data is different from the "pets" data. (Assuming `compiledTemplate` takes an array argument)

The firebase result is an object, while the pets is an array.

The template `#each` helper is expecting an array to iterate through.

You can transform the firebase object result to an array:

```js
var dataObj = snap.val()
var dataArray = Object.keys(dataObj).map(function(key) {
  return dataObj[key]
})
var ourGeneratedHTML = compiledTemplate(dataArray);
```

Also, you'll need to update the template to use the actual properties in your firebase data, and not the "pets" data.

If you're going to need to reference the object id (e.g. `Project-2`) in the template, you can do:

```
return Object.assign({}, dataObj, {id: key})
```

which just copies properties from `dataObj` into a new `{}` object, and adds the `id` field as well.

This is a good javascript reference:

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)